# How to get index number on slide in Jquery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I want to get the index of the slider on slide event.
this is my code. :

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    slide: function(event,ui){
        $('#value').text(ui.index());    
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of **ui.index()**  are you probably looking for **ui.value**?

Comment: Nope. I need to get index not value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `ui.value` property or the `$(ui.handle).index()` property?

**Please have a look at this code:**

```js
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    slide: function(event,ui){
        let index = $(ui.handle).index()
        $('#value').text("value: " + ui.value + ", index: " + index);    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="value"></div>
```

The whole situation makes more sense with a given **value set** like `[10, 25, 45, 150]`:

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  values: [10, 25, 45, 150],
  max: 200,
  change: function(event, ui) {
    var index = $(ui.handle).index();
    $("#value").text("handeled index: " + index);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: No i am looking to get index not value

Comment: What do you mean with "index". Are you looking for the dom index of the #slider element? This doesn't makes any sense for me. Please give me a small update `:)`

Comment: I have a slider which contains value from 100 - 1000. Step is set : 100. When i slide the slider on any value then i need to get its index. Slider index. Like if i slide to 200 then index would be 2.

Comment: 100 - index is 1,
200 - index is 2,
300 - index is 3,
....
so as i slide to the value i need to get its index.